# Scapy: Maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, scapy

I am trying to send broadcast message in local area network and receive a packet.
This is my code:

```
 
broadcast.dst = 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff'
# Stores the IP address and MAC address of the scanned target
request_broadcast = broadcast / request
clients = srp(request_broadcast, timeout = 1)[0]
clientInfo = dict()
for element in clients:
   print(element[1].psrc + "      " + element[1].hwsrc)
   clientInfo[element[1].psrc] = element[1].hwsrc
```

After I run this, sometimes I was able to get all the IP and MAC address but sometimes, it gives me this error:

WARNING: Socket <scapy.arch.bpf.supersocket.L2bpfSocket object at 0x103048d10> failed with 'maximum recursion depth exceeded'. It was closed.
WARNING:scapy.runtime:Socket <scapy.arch.bpf.supersocket.L2bpfSocket object at 0x103048d10> failed with 'maximum recursion depth exceeded'. It was closed.

How should I resolve this issue?

Comment: That couldn't have come from this code.  What does `srp` do?

Comment: @TimRoberts It is a scary library function that sends a packet

Comment: Is this code in a callback?  Is your request triggering a callback that causes you to issue another request?